# How to connect to AWS server with PPK file on mac

Tags: wordpress, macos, shell, amazon-web-services

How do I get on an AWS server? Do I have to use terminal? Can I use transmit? I need to install Wordpress and I really don't want to do that through command line. I have a PPK file and an amazon url. I tried converting the PPK to PEM in terminal but after spending a 4 hours of updating my OS and Xcode it didn't work. Can I get the Access key and secret from the PPK file and use that in transmit?

Comment: Can you go to the person who gave you the `.ppk` file and ask them for the `.pem` file? Then you can just use SSH on the Mac command line, or any standard SSH program. Only PuTTy on Windows uses `.ppk` files.

Answer (score 8):

You can get into AWS server from Mac terminal by using SSH protocol but for that you need `.pem` file. You can not use `.ppk` file on Mac OS to SSH into server. You need to have `.pem` file. However you can conver this `.ppk` file into `.pem`. Try following steps

1. Install Homebrew

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2. Install putty on Mac

> brew install putty

3. Convert .ppk into .pem where key.ppk is name of your .ppk file

> puttygen key.ppk -O private-openssh -o key.pem

4. Set the appropriate permissions to the .pem file

> chmod 400 key.pem

5. SSH using converted .pem file

> ssh -i key.pem username@hostname